# JSF: Check if an element is visible. If not, change/add CSS styleClass

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsf

**I have the following example code:**

```
<h:panelGroup id="element-before">Element Before</h:panelGroup>

**<h:panelGroup id="EXAMPLE-DIV" layout="block" styleClass="form-group">
   <p:outputLabel value="this is an example"/>                 
</h:panelGroup>**

<h:panelGroup id="element-after">Element After</h:panelGroup>
```

Depending on the situation, this block element **in the middle** is not shown to the user at the viewport, but by doing this **it keeps the rendered HTML elements on the source**, what leaves me with a blank space between the other two elements.

I wonder if there's a way of checking if that element is being displayed and, if it is not, I would add some css class with the property **display: none** to it.

I thought about something like the following:

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{component.isShowing() ? '':'hide-form-group'}" form-control">
</h:panelGroup>
```

Where **.hide-form-group** would contain the **display:none** property, thus eliminating my blank space.

**Appreciate any ideas on this matter.**

Comment: could you post the code seen by the browser (view source) when the middle element is not shown?

Comment: You can use `rendered` attribute `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.display}">` for the same purpose or `styleClass` as it is in question.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the reply and **I apologize for taking too long to comment back**. I'm way too rookie and  by so I'm afraid I didn't get the idea mentioned by @vasil. Exactly how can I use the **rendered="#{bean.display}"** to change/add a CSS styleClass to that element?  Also, as **Fabrizio Calderan** asked, I'm posting the part of the HTML rendered by the browser even when the component is not being shown:  '<div id="form_example:panel_example" class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-5"> </div>
</div>'

Comment: One thing you need implement is re-rendering parent of EXAMPLE-DIV panelGroup. In that case both solutions (with rendering and with styleClass) will work.